# Crystal Reports printing client side C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

I have a report that I want to fire off based on a button in a GridView.  This will generate a label and send it to an attached (local) Zebra printer.  When I run this locally, it works fine.  The printer doesn't even have to be the default.  When I copy the files to the server, and click the Print button nothing happens.

```
        CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource1 = new CrystalReportSource();
        CrystalReportViewer CrystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasPrintButton = true;
        // CrystalReportViewer1.PrintMode = "ActiveX";

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSource1;
        CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;

        CrystalReportSource1.Report.FileName = "BinLocation2.rpt";
        TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

        CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, Item);
        CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, binlocation);
        CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(2, Lot);
        CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(3, expiredate);
        CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(4, NDC);


        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SalesReportServerName"];
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SalesReportDatabaseName"];
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SalesReportUserID"];
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SalesReportPassword"];

        TableLogOnInfos infos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        infos.Add(logOnInfo);
        CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo = infos;

        try
        {

            CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
        }
```

I installed the redist packages for Visual Studio.  Compared the web.config files.  The printer is not installed on the server, but I want this done on the client side (with no prompt to print).  Is there a better way to go about doing this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is how I've achieved this functionality (explanations will follow):

```
// get the user selected printer
var printerName = Settings.Instance[profile].DirectPrinter;
// enumerate the printers visible to the application
var allPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.OfType<string>().OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
// Strip out PDF, XPS and any file based printers. These cause havoc on a server based print
var acceptablePrinters = allPrinters.Except(allPrinters
                                                .Where(s => Settings.Instance[profile].PrintersToIgnore
                                                        .Any(u => s.ToLower().Contains(u)))).ToList();
if (acceptablePrinters.Contains(printerName))
{
    report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerName;
    report.PrintToPrinter(copies, collate, 0, 0);
}
else
{
   // Log the reason why the printer was rejected
   // Or you may choose to just print to default
}
```

Explanation

The PrintToPrinter method runs on the server side, so it will only work with printers that the server and the IIS application pool identity can 'see'.

Most Zebra printers will be networked, so with configuration can be made visible across the entire network. However, you need to allow configuration in your asp.net application to set a printer name at runtime (even if it's always the same), and then you can call PrintToPrinter that will print to a networked printer.

Printing to client **without a prompt** is practically impossible, and ill advised. For that I allow the user to choose to print to client and then export to PDF, and the standard PDF print dialog box prompts the user for his printer settings. This was added to allow printing to non-networked printers.

Comment: "Most Zebra printers will be networked" - that's not the case here.  The printers are connected locally through USB. I'm testing a 3rd party control that should allow what I want.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can access network shared USB printers from an ASP.net application, I have a number of deployments using this option. I'm still looking for a more robust client printing option, and I'm open to suggestions, so what is this 3rd party control?

Comment: http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-Directly-Print-Crystal-Reports-to-Default-Client-Printer-from-ASP-NET-without-Preview-or-Printer-Dialog/

Comment: Wow! This looks really promising, and not expensive either! Even though I still want to show a dialog for client prints, it will be great to have the option. Thank you.

Comment: So far support has been excellent, and outside of some minor issues, the software has worked.  The software is basically a DLL that opens Adobe on the client PC, does the export and then prints the PDF automatically.  But you have some flexibility via code.